# Filter rejected Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I have an array of `Promise` objects where I want to map on and filter the rejected Promises.

Expected output:

```
const promises = [
  failedPromise,
  successPromise,
  successPromise,
];

const resolvedPromises = promises.map(promise => ???);
```

The `resolvedPromises` variable should container the output of the two `successPromise` promises.

How would I implement such algorithm?

Comment: how are the failed differentiated from the non-failed? what do the two objects look like?

Comment: Have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30930421/1048572). Notice that it's impossible to synchronously determine the state of a promise, so the best you will get is a promise for an array of fufilled promises (or their results)

Answer (score 11):

You can't inspect standard promises in a synchronous way, so you cannot filter the array by their resolution status. But you can employ [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to get a list of outcomes. Thanks to @O-2 in the comments. Example code to get only resolved values:

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.reject(2),
  Promise.resolve(3)
];


const resolvedPromises = Promise.allSettled(promises).then(
  values => values.filter(o => o.status === 'fulfilled').map(o => o.value)
);

resolvedPromises.then(values => console.log(values));
```

Comment: In ES6, I'd even use `Symbol("failed")` instead of an empty object.

Comment: I think `allSettled()` would be better. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Comment: @O-9 you are right! In 2023, `Promise.allSettled` is a better answer, thank you!